# How to write this Rails 4.2 js asset path

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have this in a .js file that is in the vendor directory:

```
arrowpointers:{
    downarrow: ["img/arrow-down.png", 11,7], //[path_to_down_arrow, arrowwidth, arrowheight]
    rightarrow: ["img/arrow-right.png", 12,12], //[path_to_right_arrow, arrowwidth, arrowheight]
    showarrow: {toplevel: true, sublevel: true} //Show arrow images on top level items and sub level items, respectively?
   },
```

I can't get the `arrow-down.png` and the `arrow-right.png` to show. I've tried every combination of asset and image path, url, etc. All the images are in the `app/assets/images` folder. Every other image works fine but this I can't figure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change the file extension to `js.erb`, so that we can embed ruby code in it.
Add the images inside `app/assets/images` folder.
Then add this line in `application.rb` to enable assets,

```
class Application < Rails::Application
 #add this line
 config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css *.png *.jpg *.jpeg )
end
```

And finally make this change in your `js.erb` file,

```
arrowpointers:{
    downarrow: ['<%= asset_path("arrow-down.png") %>', 11,7], //[path_to_down_arrow, arrowwidth, arrowheight]
    rightarrow: ['<%= asset_path("arrow-right.png") %>', 12,12], //[path_to_right_arrow, arrowwidth, arrowheight]
    showarrow: {toplevel: true, sublevel: true} //Show arrow images on top level items and sub level items, respectively?
   },
```

Comment: I did everything you said. It didn't work. Those arrow images do not show up.

Comment: What error message does it show in rails console? Did you place the images in `app/assets/images` folder?

Comment: How would I see that error in the console? I'm not that experienced to find errors in console.

Comment: Ok instead of that you can open console in firefox or chrome and check if there is any error messages displayed regarding image not found. For checking error in rails console go to the terminal window where server is running, check for any 404 issues, stating that arrow-down.png image not found. Plus now when the webpage is loaded, what does it show inplace of ruby code in the js present in the page source code.